# If $X \subseteq G$, $\langle X^{G}\rangle$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X^{G} = \{gxg^{-1}: g \in G, x \in X\}$, and define $$\langle X^{G}\rangle = \bigcap_{H \in A} H,$$ where $A=\{H \leq G: X^{G} \subseteq H\}$. We wish to show that $\langle X^{G}\rangle$ is normal in $G$. I've been trying to show $gag^{-1}$ belongs to $\langle X^{G}\rangle$ for arbitrary $g \in G$ and $a \in \langle X^{G}\rangle$. Any hints on the best way to show this would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Some MathJax advice:

`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Thank you! I had trouble finding the proper code.

Comment: Show that if $H$ is a subset of $G$, and $g$ is an element of $G$, then $H \in A$ if and only if $gHg^{-1} \in A$. Draw a conclusion about the relation between $\bigcup\limits_{H \in A} H$ and $\bigcup\limits_{H \in A} gHg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alternate characterization of the subgroup $\langle B \rangle$ generated by a subset $B \subset G$, namely, $\langle B \rangle$ is the set of all elements of $G$ which can be written as a product $b_1 b_2 \ldots b_K$ for some sequence $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_K \in B \cup B^{-1}$.

Any $a \in \langle X^G \rangle$ can therefore be written in the form
$$a = (g_1 x_1 g_1^{-1}) (g_2 x_2 g_2^{-1}) \ldots (g_K x_K g_K^{-1})
$$
where $g_1,\ldots,g_K \in G$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_K \in X \cup X^{-1}$. Given $g \in G$ we then have
\begin{align*}
gag^{-1} &= g (g_1 x_1 g_1^{-1}) (g_2 x_2 g_2^{-1}) \ldots (g_K x_K g_K^{-1}) g^{-1} \\
&=\bigl(g (g_1 x_1 g_1^{-1})g^{-1}\bigr) \bigl(g (g_2 x_2 g_2^{-1}) g^{-1} \bigr) \ldots \bigl(g(g_K x_K g_K^{-1}) g^{-1}\bigr) \\
&= \bigl((gg_1) x_1 (gg_1)^{-1}\bigr) \bigl((gg_2) x_2 (gg_2)^{-1}\bigr) \ldots \bigl((gg_K) x_K (gg_K)^{-1}\bigr)
\end{align*}
which is in $\langle X^G \rangle$.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you. Out of curiosity,  how would you suggest proving normality by the definition in the original post. The comment above isn't flipping on the light switch for me.

Comment: @dgc1240: To be honest, I would probably do it by first proving the lemma which says that the two characterizations of $\langle B \rangle$ are equivalent.